# Dropdown list onchange can't display dropdown list

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 dropdown. States/Divisions and Townships. Townships dropdown is blank. If I choose something in the S/D dropdown, Township dropdown changes according to the S/D selection. But I can't see the dropdown list in the Township and it's just white. Can someone help me please?

It's work but the changes in township dropdown list are blank.

My controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Township_Filter(string id)
    {
        List<string> tsp = db.TB_Township.Where(t => t.StateDivisionID.Equals(id)).Select(t => t.Township).ToList();
        return Json(tsp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My Ajax call

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StateDivision").on("change", function () {
            var sdID = $("#StateDivision").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/LoanMaster/Township_Filter',
                data: {id : sdID},
                beforeSend: function(){

                },
                success: function (tsp) {
                    if(tsp != null)
                    {
                        $('#Township').empty();

                        $('#Township').append($('<option value="">--Choose--</option>'));
                        for (i = 0; i < tsp.length; i++)
                        {
                            $('#Township').append($('<option value="' + tsp[i] + '>"' + tsp[i] + '</option>'));
                        }
                    }
                },

                complete: function () {

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My View

```
            <select id="StateDivision" class="form-control">
                <option>--Choose--</option>
                <option value="100">A</option>
                <option value="101">B</option>
            </select>

            <select id="Township" class="form-control abc">
                <option>--Choose--</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Can you console.log 'tsp' in the success callback?

Comment: @VincentChinner here it is - 
Array(12)
0: "သန်လျင်မြို့နယ်"
1: "ကျောက်တန်း"
2: "သုံးခွ"
3: "ခရမ်း"
4: "တွံတေး"
5: "ကွမ်းခြံကုန်း"
6: "အင်းစိန်"
7: "မှော်ဘီ"
8: "တိုက်ကြီး"
9: "လှည်းကူး"
10: "ထန်းတပင်"
11: "ကော့မူး"
length: 12

Comment: $('<option value="' + tsp[i] + '>" ' + tsp[i] + '</option>') there is a syntax error. try this $('<option value=" ' + tsp[i] + ' ">' + tsp[i] + '</option>')

Comment: Oh.. yes it's correct now. I'm so blind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error

```
$('<option value="' + tsp[i] + '>" ' + tsp[i] + '</option>')
```

maybe that's why. try This

```
$('<option value="' + tsp[i] + '">' + tsp[i] + '</option>')
```